# Zoom animation with a UICollectionView inside a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to animate the transition from a UICollectionViewController to a UIViewController.

**TLDR: in the last function, how can I get the frame that will take the navigation bar into account?**

Each cell has a UIImageView, and I want to zoom in on it as I transition to the view controller. This is similar to the Photos app, except that the image is not centered and there are other views around (labels, etc.).

The UIImageView is placed using AutoLayout, centered horizontally and 89pts from the top safe layout guide.

It almost works, except that I can't manage to get the proper frame for the target UIImageView, it doesn't take into account the navigation and so the frame y origin is off by as much.

My `UICollectionViewController` is the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

```
class CollectionViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == detailSegue,
            let destination = segue.destination as? CustomViewController,
            let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }
        navigationController?.delegate = self
        …
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        switch operation {
        case .push:
            return ZoomInAnimator()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The `ZoomInAnimator` object looks like that:

```
open class ZoomInAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    public func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }

public func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
            let fromContent = (fromViewController  as? ZoomAnimatorDelegate)?.animatedContent(),
            let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
            let toContent = (toViewController as? ZoomAnimatorDelegate)?.animatedContent() else { return }

        let finalFrame = toContent.pictureFrame!

        // Set pre-animation state
        toViewController.view.alpha = 0
        toContent.picture.isHidden = true

        // Add a new UIImageView where the "from" picture currently is
        let transitionImageView = UIImageView(frame: fromContent.pictureFrame)
        transitionImageView.image = fromContent.picture.image
        transitionImageView.contentMode = fromContent.picture.contentMode
        transitionImageView.clipsToBounds = fromContent.picture.clipsToBounds

        transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
        transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(transitionImageView)

        // Animate the transition
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0,
            options: [.transitionCrossDissolve],
            animations: {
                transitionImageView.frame = finalFrame
                toViewController.view.alpha = 1
        }) { completed in
            transitionImageView.removeFromSuperview()
            toContent.picture.isHidden = false
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I ask both controllers for their UIImageViews and their frames using `animatedContent()`. This function is defined in both the UICollectionViewController and the UIViewController, which both conforms to this protocol:

```
protocol ZoomAnimatorDelegate {
    func animatedContent() -> AnimatedContent?
}
```

With `AnimatedContent` being a simple struct:

```
struct AnimatedContent {
    let picture: UIImageView!
    let pictureFrame: CGRect!
}
```

Here's how that function is implemented on both sides.

This side works fine (the UICollectionViewController / fromViewController in the transition):

```
extension CollectionViewController: ZoomAnimatorDelegate {

    func animatedContent() -> AnimatedContent? {
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else { return nil }
        let cell = cellOrPlaceholder(for: indexPath) // Custom method to get the cell, I'll skip the details
        let frame = cell.convert(cell.picture.frame, to: view)
        return AnimatedContent(picture: cell.picture, pictureFrame: frame)
    }
}
```

**This is the problematic part.**

**The picture frame origin is 89pts and ignores the navigation bar which adds a 140pt offset. I tried all sorts of convert(to:) without any success. Also, I'm a bit concerned about calling `view.layoutIfNeeded` here, is it the way to do it?**

```
class ViewController: ZoomAnimatorDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!
    func animatedContent() -> AnimatedContent? {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        return AnimatedContent(picture: picture, profilePictureFrame: picture.frame)
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's an updated version of `animateTransition` (not using snapshots yet, but I'll get there)

```
public func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as? CollectionViewController,
        let fromContent = fromViewController.animatedContent(),
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) as? ViewController,
        let toImageView = toViewController.picture else { return }

    transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
    toViewController.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
    toViewController.view.setNeedsLayout()
    toViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    let finalFrame = toViewController.view.convert(toImageView.frame, to: transitionContext.containerView)

    let transitionImageView = UIImageView(frame: fromContent.pictureFrame)
    transitionImageView.image = fromContent.picture.image
    transitionImageView.contentMode = fromContent.picture.contentMode
    transitionImageView.clipsToBounds = fromContent.picture.clipsToBounds
    transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(transitionImageView)

    // Set pre-animation state
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0
    toImageView.isHidden = true

    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
        initialSpringVelocity: 0,
        options: [.transitionCrossDissolve],
        animations: {
            transitionImageView.frame = finalFrame
            toViewController.view.alpha = 1
    }) { completed in
        transitionImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        toImageView.isHidden = false
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are obtaining the final frame incorrectly:

```
let finalFrame = toContent.pictureFrame!
```

Here's what you should have done:

1. Start by asking the transition context for the final frame of the `to` view controller’s view, by calling `finalFrame(for:)`. The fact that you never call that method is a clear bug; you should *always* call it!
2. Now use that as either the frame to animate to (if you know that the image will fill it completely), or use it as the basis of the calculation of that frame.

   What I do in the latter case is to perform a dummy layout operation to learn what the image frame will be within the view controller’s view, and then *convert* the coordinate system to that of the transition context. The fact that I don't see you performing any coordinate system conversion is a sign of another bug in your code. Remember, `frame` is calculated in terms of a view's superview's coordinate system.

Here’s an example from one of my apps; it’s a presented VC not a pushed VC, but that makes no difference to the calculation:

[image]

Observe how I know where the red swatch *will be* in the final frame of the presented view controller's view, and I move the red swatch snapshot to that frame in terms of the transition context's coordinate system.

Also note that I use a snapshot view as a proxy. You are using a loose image view as a proxy and that might be fine too.

Comment: So with 1/ I moved the layoutIfNeeded into the animateTransition, but I'm still struggling with 2/. I basically call that toViewController.view.convert(toViewController.picture.frame, to: transitionContext.containerView) but it's still to high (not taking the nav bar into account).

Comment: Well, you've got all this protocol "delegate" stuff in the way that I don't understand. There is a real view controller out there that is trying to come into the picture, it has a real view, that view does some sort of layout and is going to display an image in a certain location, you need to find out what that location is going to be. I mean, I've told you what _I_ do and I've shown you that it works. I don't see what else there is.

Comment: It's just used to get the UIImageView on both sides (the one in the currently selected cell and the one in the "to" view controller). Does it make sense? I got that from https://github.com/masamichiueta/FluidPhoto but it looks like it's not a great example of how to do things.

Comment: I edited my question to add my current version of animateTransition. It doesn't use the protocol anymore for the destination view.

Comment: I solved it. I wasn't calling convert on the proper view, it had to be the imageview's superview.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm still accepting your answer because it helped me a lot. Thanks for your time on SO, it's always a pleasure to read your contributions.

Comment: Excellent! I did say in my answer “frame is calculated in terms of a view's superview's coordinate system” and “frame in terms of the transition context's coordinate system”.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely on me. My imageview is in a stack, and I was calling convert using the toViewController.view instead of profile.superview (which is the stackview).

Comment: Just bought the app that helped solve this as a small token of gratitude ;)

Comment: LOL but I assure you that’s not why I used it as an example, it was just an animated gif I already had handy.

Comment: Haha, I know, but I thought it was a fun way to conclude this exchange.